# Jquery insert data from variable into dynamic input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to insert data into an input that is labeled.  "Proposed Destruction Date"  Unfortunately the ids and name are dynamic and can't be used.  I am attempting to find the label then the next input after the label.  I am lost on the best way to do this.

Here is the code from the label and input.  I don't have control over.

```js
$("label:contains('Proposed Destruction Date:')").css("background-color", "green");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="x-form-item " tabindex="-1" id="ext-gen234">
   <label for="ext-comp-1071" style="width:154px;" class="x-form-item-label" id="ext-gen235">Proposed Destruction Date:</label>
   <div class="x-form-element" id="x-form-el-ext-comp-1071" style="padding-left:159px">
     <div class="x-form-field-wrap x-form-field-trigger-wrap" id="ext-gen236" style="width: 95px;">
       <input type="text" size="10" autocomplete="off" id="ext-comp-1071" name="DEST1-2596" class="x-form-text x-form-field" style="width: 70px;">
       <img src="/LMS/js1910280933/ext/resources/images/default/s.gif" alt="" class="x-form-trigger x-form-date-trigger" id="ext-gen237">
     </div>
     <div class="lms-form-field-msg-area" style="left:262px;" id="ext-gen238">
      <span id="ext-comp-1071-msg" class="lms-form-field-error"></span>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="x-form-clear-left">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code I have written to try and find this input.  So far I can't find the label or if I can it is not turning green.  Please let me know if there is a better way to find this input with out the id or name since those change.

Thanks for all your help

Comment: When converted into a code snippet in the question, it appears to work as expected.  Can you clarify the problem?  For example, in the actual code where specifically are these segments placed?  Are you trying to execute the JavaScript *before* the HTML loads?

Comment: As above: snippets in SO always append the scripts box to the output *after* the HTML so don't have the same issue.  If it works here, but doesn't work for OP then it's likely `doc.ready` is required.

Comment: The following is working ```$("label:contains('Proposed Destruction Date:') + .x-form-element input").val(dts1);```   I have a followup question this is a date field in the first input box it is in "MM/DD/YYY"  when I move it from the variable to the second input it is"YYYY/MM/DD" How can I control it in the variable.  I can create a new question if needed.  I would like it to show "MM/DD/YYYY" in the second box if you type it manually that is how it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` matches the next sibling
You could also have used .next() to traverse.  `~` will match all next siblings, if you need to find all following siblings.

```js
$("label:contains('Proposed Destruction Date:') + .x-form-element input").css("background-color", "green");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="x-form-item " tabindex="-1" id="ext-gen234">
   <label for="ext-comp-1071" style="width:154px;" class="x-form-item-label" id="ext-gen235">Proposed Destruction Date:</label>
   <div class="x-form-element" id="x-form-el-ext-comp-1071" style="padding-left:159px">
     <div class="x-form-field-wrap x-form-field-trigger-wrap" id="ext-gen236" style="width: 95px;">
       <input type="text" size="10" autocomplete="off" id="ext-comp-1071" name="DEST1-2596" class="x-form-text x-form-field" style="width: 70px;">
       <img src="/LMS/js1910280933/ext/resources/images/default/s.gif" alt="" class="x-form-trigger x-form-date-trigger" id="ext-gen237">
     </div>
     <div class="lms-form-field-msg-area" style="left:262px;" id="ext-gen238">
      <span id="ext-comp-1071-msg" class="lms-form-field-error"></span>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="x-form-clear-left">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much this works now I just have to insert the variable.